# Accessing Mysql from multiple EC2 instance Issue

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, instance

**I want to know that Is it possible that create mysql database from EC2 Instance 1 and you can access same database from Instance 2 ?**

Actually I have created two instance on aws and I have created mysql database from instance 1 and I want to access same database in Instance 2.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. it is possible. But I would suggest using RDS in that case.

Comment: If it is possible. How can I get this? @BikashPaul